# Colorscheme is not changing anything in vim

Tags: vim, colors, color-scheme

I'm typing `:colorscheme desert` or `:colorscheme default` or any other type of colorscheme in my vim, and I'm just getting the same one colorered text for my code with a black background. I would like the text in my files to have multiple colors to distinguish things but don't know how to do this

Comment: Do you have syntax highlighting turned on?  Your .vimrc should have `syntax on`

Comment: You also need to use a color-capable terminal type, such as `xterm` or `xterm-256color`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could provide your `.vimrc` and `:version`.

You may be missing any of these:

- `syntax on`
- `set t_Co=256`
- `filetype plugin indent on`

Comment: No. Not `set t_Co=256`, please.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: Color support is supposed to be configured at the terminal emulator level. Not in your `vimc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check how the colorscheme is rendered via `:hi`. If all you see is black and white, Vim probably does not recognize your (color) terminal, and `:set t_Co?` will output `2` [colors]. Check your `$TERM` setting then.